# Size a (square) image so that the drawing is wholly contained in a circle

Tags: inkscape, gimp, alignment

I’m having this problem with both GIMP (for bitmaps) and Inkscape (for vector drawings), so solutions for either are welcome, as I need both anyway.

Many applications have started to crop user-uploaded avatars or other pictures first to a square (by using the smaller edge length) then to a full-sized circle inlaid that square.

To counter this, before uploading I would like to pad the image (resize and possibly move) so that the entire drawing (i.e. anything not background) is contained within the target area.

Example: starting from…

[image: start image]

… resize the outer image (not needed here¹, but do as necessary) so that it fits inside the circle…

[image: with circle]

… but do not actually add the circle to the image:

[image: desired result]

So when I upload this, the drawing (here, the text “foo”) is wholly contained in the circle.

The solution must be precise (i.e. no manual mouse-moving and resizing until it fits) and **should** be automated / batched. For GIMP this includes scripting; for Inkscape (SVG can be assumed) this may even involve XML editing, XSLT, etc. (but having a solution *at all* will be worthwhile).

① not needed here because I cheated by drawing the circle first and resizing the drawing to fit; ideally, starting from a nōn-square image would also work

Comment: What should happen with the edges when for example the image is a square? If some algorithm scales the square down to fit within the circle there will be transparent edges.

Comment: @Wolff I don’t understand the question. If the starting image is, say, a filled square of foreground colour, then the end result should be a larger square of background colour (or transparency, I can fill that myself) where the initial image is fully contained in the centre.

Comment: I just mean to automate it, you need the program to understand what you want to happen in all cases. I can just see many different cases. If you can live with the "lowest common denominator" you could just find out which percentage to scale a square to fit into a circle with the same diameter as the side of the square, and just use that same scale factor for all images after making sure they fit into a square.

Comment: But not all drawings extend to the edge of the enclosing rectangle.

Comment: Then trim them first, change the canvas to a square and expand the canvas afterwards to get the proper margin. But the more I think about this the more different cases I see. For example if you have some image with a center like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EIAS.png), wouldn't you rather keep the original center like in b than fill the circle like in c? And if you have a square image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg6gP.png), wouldn't you rather crop the image to the circle like in b than fit the square inside the circle like in c?

Comment: @Wolff in most cases I’d like the image moved as well. In this question, I’m mostly talking about drawings, not photographies; I’m fully aware this won’t work with the cute cat photo, but that’s not the scope. This question is basically for when I do *not* want to let the site crop the thing.

Comment: Also consider (hmm, this probably should extend the question instead) I have a larger cat photo and need to find a cutout section that, when made square, will fit all of the cat… hmm… another case to consider (though for GIMP only, not for Inkscape). I think we’ll just need multiple solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Possible answer for Gimp:

`ofn-enclosing-circle` (available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)) determines the [smallest circle that encloses the shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) and does things with it.

[image]

Note that on your image it doesn't produce the circle that you expect:

[image]

.. but the circle is a tighter fit (294 px vs 300px).

If you look at the Wikipedia article the smallest circle is either defined by a diameter (two points on the shape that are diametrically opposed) or by three points (three points of the shape are on the circle).